# Force inclusion of a header in project

Tags: c++

I have a header with a particular set of rules that the user must follow. If the user does not want to follow the rules, they must define a preprocessor macro which will disable the checks. If the user is using the library, the user must include the header in every one of their classes that uses any code from the library or explicitly state otherwise by the above mentioned preprocessor (in this case, the header may be included implicitly [using one of the library's classes] which is fine):

```
// User using my library, they must include the BaseHeader.h or otherwise use the following define
// #define NOT_USING_BASE_HEADER //(can of course be defined project wide)
#include <BaseHeader.h>
// ... other includes (not necessarily from my library)
class Foo
{
  //...
};
```

Is there a way to accomplish this? Keep in mind that the base header is also being included

Comment: What are the rules like?  Are they things understood by the compiler, or just some text for humans to read?  What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: Can't you just have all of your library's other header files include the BaseHeader.h file?

Comment: Don't even go there. C++ must be used by people who understand the language and design, *forcing* something upon a developer is a sign of something wrong with either the developer or those who forcing it.

Comment: @Gene: I disagree... enforcing rules can help you as well. In this case, the user can be me and I may forget to follow certain rules and end up spending some times trying to find out why (setting configuration properties for a C++ project with many configurations is a pain let alone checking it to make sure they are as per the rules). For example, in my projects I don't want exception handling and I want to make absolutely sure that is the case. I also want to make sure there is no CRT mismatch of static/dll linkage. I find that this is very helpful in making absolutely sure my project...

Comment: ...settings are valid (does not mean the library can't work with exception handling, it is just that I want it disabled for the many projects that I am working on, including projects that are libraries within this framework). I just wanted to know if there was a way to force it but also allow the user the flexibility to NOT include it as long as they are aware of what they are doing.

Comment: Not sure why the downvote (don't mind the down-vote, but an explanation would be nice). Google enforces that they use no exceptions in their projects... not saying `because Google is doing it, it must be right` but saying that I have support for enforcing rules :) ... anyway, I wish SO would stop taking a very one-sided `enterprise development` approach to everything.

Comment: I agree Samaursa. Partly, I've seen very good third-party softwares that are used and paid for and considered very high-quality that enforce similar rules of which you are trying to do. I also agree that users on SO are incredibly enterprise development approached to everything, which honestly makes me quite sad.

Comment: Not to mention how often people stop commenting just because they're wrong and won't admit it.

Comment: @Gene: I must add this, even if it means some more down-votes. Your quote `C++ must be used by people who understand the language and design` sounds very arrogant (I don't mean you come off as arrogant, just that quote, and I am sorry if this was rude) and a few people at SO share that stance unfortunately. C++ can be used by anybody. That is how you became better at it, that is how I am getting better at it, and that is how every newcomer will learn the language. If everyone who used C++ understood the language and design we wouldn't have SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your question entirely, but do you think this will help?

BaseHeader.h:

```
#pragma once
#define BASE_HEADER_INCLUDED
...
```

internal_header.h:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef NOT_USING_BASE_HEADER
   #ifdef BASE_HEADER_INCLUDED
      #error You can't both define NOT_USING_BASE_HEADER and include the base-header-file.
   #endif
   ... 
#elseif defined BASE_HEADER_INCLUDED
   ...
#else
   #error You have to either define NOT_USING_BASE_HEADER or include the base header file!
#endif
```

If you want to make it so that it doesn't take "internal" includes of the baseheader.h, then you have to add/remove a define to make sure that it doesn't define it:

internal_header.h:

```
#pragma once

#define SKIP_HEADER_DEFINE
#include 
#undef SKIP_HEADER_DEFINE
```

And in BaseHeader.h:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef SKIP_HEADER_DEFINE
   #define BASE_HEADER_INCLUDED
#endif
```

Cheers,
Simon

Comment: So the rules go in `internal_header` as well as `BaseHeader`?

Comment: Unfortunately yeah. In most cases you can come around with just having a simple define in your internal_header OR one that is defined externally. Then you probably need to do the rules internally. You can probably make some simplified macros for it though.

Comment: Ok that makes sense and works for me in my case. I have created another header that is internal which is included by both these headers so I don't have to type rules twice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I see at least two choices:

1. Document that the users must do this. This needs to be right up front, not buried ten miles deep. You are making any use of your library that doesn't follow your rules undefined behavior (obviously not UB as far as the language is concerned, but as far as your library its UB because you said so).
2. Do it for them. Make all of your headers #include BaseHeader.h. Don't give the user the option of invoking UB or otherwise screwing up.

BTW, BaseHeader.h is not the best name for a library header. You are asking for name collisions, and that is C++ undefined behavior, and that UB is your fault.

Comment: `BaseHeader.h` is not the name... to avoid stepping on any NDA clauses, I did not mention the name but came up with one that fit the context of the question (I may be overly cautious here)

Comment: Point taken, Samaursa. Its always good to be a bit cautious when it comes to giving away trade secrets, etc.